# Notice: Undefined variable: id in line 9

Tags: pdo, count

I am trying to increment the id each time a query is done.. In the first code I get error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: id in line 9

`$q->execute(array($id));`

The second code is the increment...

http://pastebin.com/G83UYm8e

http://pastebin.com/aXFkWNyD

Answer (score 0):

When creating your table, also add a column for the ID, make it auto-increment, and make it the primary key. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Now you don't have to worry about incrementing the ID in your PHP code. MySQL will do it for you.